# Finding maximum value and their indices in a sparse lil_matrix (Scipy/Python)

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

What's the best way to find the maximum value and their corresponding row and column indices in a Scipy sparse [lil_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html) object ? I can [loop through the nonzero entries using itertools.izip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319014/iterating-through-a-scipy-sparse-vector-or-matrix), but is there anything better ? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could convert to COO format, and then use the `data`, `row` and `col` attributes.

For example, suppose the LIL matrix is `x`.  Here's one way to get the maximum value along with its row and column:

```
In [41]: x
Out[41]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1999 stored elements in LInked List format>

In [42]: y = x.tocoo()

In [43]: k = y.data.argmax()

In [44]: maxval = y.data[k]

In [45]: maxrow = y.row[k]

In [46]: maxcol = y.col[k]
```

*Note:* There are two bugs in the above code:

- If all the nonzero values are negative, it will find the largest negative value.  But the correct answer should be 0 in that case.
- If there are *no* nonzero values, then the line `k = y.data.argmax()` will raise an exception, because `y.data` is an empty array.

If those cases can't happen in your application, then those bugs can be ignored.

Comment: That saved me a lot of time. Thanks!