# Optimizing iteration using itertools.izip

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have an algorithm that iterates through all of the nonzero values of a matrix which looks something like this:

```
for row, col, val in itertools.izip(matrix.row, matrix.col, matrix.data):
    dostuff(row, col, val)
```

I realize that this is the fastest way of iterating through a sparse matrix in `numpy`, as was discussed in [Iterating through a scipy.sparse vector (or matrix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319014/iterating-through-a-scipy-sparse-vector-or-matrix).

My problem is that the function I perform at each evaluation takes another vector, let's call it `vec`, and does nothing if `vec[row]` is equal to `0`, which in some cases is true for the majority of rows.

Therefore, I do not want to iterate through all the nonzero triplets `(row, col, val)` in the matrix for which `vec[row] != 0`.

What I currently do is the simple and stupid solution of

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
import itertools

N = 10000
matrix = sp.rand(N, N, density=0.0001, format='coo', dtype=None, random_state=None)
vec = np.zeroes(N)
s = 0
for row, col, val in itertools.izip(matrix.row, matrix.col, matrix.data):
    if vec[row] != 0:
        s += vec[row] * val # in reality, some other function is here
```

which works and works quicker than the original code if there are not many rows with `vec[row]!=0`. However, the code runs slowly in the case when all values of `vec` are nonzero, and that is a case I am not allowed to ignore (for example, if `vec=np.ones(len(matrix.data))`.

Therefore, I need some sort of extension of `izip` which will allow me to "conditionally" iterate through its output, so that I would write something like

```
for row, col, val in itertools.izip(matrix.row, matrix.col, matrix.data, lambda x: vec[x[0]] !> 0):
    dostuff(row, col, val)
```

What are your suggestions? What will be the quickest way to do this?

Comment: Well, you're still missing an import. But close enough; I was able to test my ideas and get them working and that's the important part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use Numpy's special indexing on the rows, columns and data:

```
which = vec[matrix.row] != 0

rows = matrix.row[which]
cols = matrix.col[which]
data = matrix.data[which]

for row, col, val in itertools.izip(rows, cols, data):
    s += vec[row] * val
```

Comment: That looks wonderful, thank you. I will try it out to see how much faster my algorithm becomes. If you don't mind, I will leave the question open for a while to see if some other suggestions come in, otherwise I will accept this question.

Comment: Whis is an amazing solution. The original code now still runs about 20 percent faster than the modified code if `vec` has no nonzero elements, but if `vec` is sparse, this code quicker by 2 to 3 orders of magnitude. Thank you.