# finding y index of a sparse 2D matrix by its value in python

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a 2D sparse matrix `"unknown_tfidf"`in size of (1000,10000) which type is :

```
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

I need to get y index of this matrix where value is `'1'`,I am trying the following method (not sure if it is optimal or even right way!) but I am facing an error:

```
y=[row.index(1.0) for index, row in enumerate(unknown_tfidf) if int(1.0) in row]
```

and the error is :

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

my question is how can I get only all the y-indices of such matrix where matrix value is 1?

Comment: The `ValueError` is caused by trying to use a boolean array in a scalar `if` context, i.e. your `if <a boolean array>` phrase.

Comment: I have tried many forms in that if-statement but I still have the same error! is there any way, any converter or other efficient method to be able to apply such if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension works for a nested list

```
In [100]: xl=[[0,1,3],[0,0,1],[1,1,0]]
In [101]: [row.index(1) for index, row in enumerate(xl) if 1 in row]
Out[101]: [1, 2, 0]
```

(note that `index` returns just the first match in the third row).

but does not work for a `numpy.array`:

```
In [102]: xa=np.array(xl)
In [103]: [row.index(1) for index, row in enumerate(xa) if 1 in row]
...
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

and not for a sparse matrix:

```
In [104]: xs=sparse.csr_matrix(xl)
In [105]: xs
Out[105]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [106]: [row.index(1) for index, row in enumerate(xs) if 1 in row]
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

If I remove the `if` test I get a different error, a variation on the dense array error.

```
In [108]: [row.index(1) for index, row in enumerate(xs)]
...
AttributeError: index not found
```

Look at what the enumerate gives us to work with;

```
In [109]: [(index,row) for index, row in enumerate(xs)]
Out[109]: 
[(0, <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>),
 (1, <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>),
 (2, <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>)]
```

`row` is a another sparse matrix, the same as `xs[0]`, etc.  So the `1 in row` and `row.index(1)` expressions have to work with an array or matrix, else you get an error.

We've already seen that neither has the `index` method.  That is a list method - you have to use something else for arrays or sparse matrices.  Your comprehension has the `if` clause because the list `index` raises a error if that item is not found.  In that sense the `if in` and `index` go together.

`in` works for an array, but gives value error for the sparse matrix:

```
In [114]: 1 in xa[0]
Out[114]: True
In [115]: 1 in xs[0]
....
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

More commonly this ValueError is produced by the equivalent of:

```
In [117]: if np.array([True, False, True]):'yes'
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

that is, giving an `if` a boolean array.  In your case this failure occurs within the `sparse` code.  In effect `in` has not been implemented for sparse.

So if you insist on using this list comprehension approach, you'll have to turn your sparse matrix into a list of lists:

```
In [120]: [row.index(1) for index, row in enumerate(xs.toarray().tolist()) if 1 in row]
Out[120]: [1, 2, 0]
```

---

Here's a variation on `unutbu's` answer:

Use a matrix/array equality test to find ALL the elements that match:

```
In [121]: xs==1
Out[121]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [122]: (xs==1).A
Out[122]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Then use a builtin method to get the indices of those `True` elements:

```
In [123]: (xs==1).nonzero()
Out[123]: (array([0, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int32), array([1, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int32))
```

The second element of that tuple is the list you want (with 2 values for the 3rd row).

Or to collect values for rows (remember, in iterating each row is a matrix)

```
In [125]: [i.nonzero() for i in (xs==1)]
Out[125]: 
[(array([0], dtype=int32), array([1], dtype=int32)),
 (array([0], dtype=int32), array([2], dtype=int32)),
 (array([0, 0], dtype=int32), array([0, 1], dtype=int32))]
```

reducing that list to simple list of indices takes more fiddling

```
In [131]: [i.nonzero()[1].tolist() for i in (xs==1)]
Out[131]: [[1], [2], [0, 1]]
```

Comment: wow!thank you so much! now I get the point and of course both solutions work properly in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The index of the *columns* where the Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) matrix equals 1 are stores in its `.indices` attribute:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sparse
np.random.seed(2016)

arr = np.round(10*sparse.rand(10, 10, density=0.8, format='csr'))
# arr.A
# array([[  5.,   0.,   7.,   7.,   8.,   7.,   0.,   2.,   4.,   2.],
#        [  4.,   0.,   9.,   2.,   4.,   8.,   4.,   2.,   5.,   9.],
#        [  7.,   4.,   4.,   2.,   4.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   6.,   0.],
#        [  8.,   0.,   0.,   7.,   0.,   6.,   5.,   8.,   0.,   3.],
#        [  3.,   5.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   7.,   3.,   8.,   3.,   0.],
#        [  8.,   6.,   7.,   0.,   8.,   2.,   7.,   0.,   1.,   1.],
#        [  4.,   6.,   3.,   1.,   8.,   7.,   8.,   6.,   0.,   2.],
#        [  7.,   7.,   0.,  10.,   6.,   2.,   4.,   2.,   1.,  10.],
#        [ 10.,   0.,   4.,   8.,   1.,   1.,   3.,   1.,   9.,   1.],
#        [  0.,   4.,   0.,   0.,   7.,   2.,  10.,   1.,   9.,   0.]])

condition = (arr == 1)
print(condition.indices)
```

yields

```
[2 8 9 3 8 4 5 7 9 7]
```

[The fastest way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4319014/190597) to find both the row and column indices where `arr` equals 1, is to convert `arr` to a COO matrix, then read off its `row` and `col` attributes:

```
coo = condition.tocoo()
print(coo.row)
print(coo.col)
```

yields

```
[4 5 5 6 7 8 8 8 8 9]
[2 8 9 3 8 4 5 7 9 7]
```

Comment: The `sparse` `nonzero` method essentially does that (convert to `coo`)  (with an added test in case there 0's in `.data`).