# Efficiently applying a threshold function to SciPy sparse csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, array-broadcasting

I have a SciPy csr_matrix (a vector in this case) of 1 column and x rows. In it are float values which I need to convert to the discrete class labels -1, 0 and 1. This should be done with a threshold function which maps the float values to one of these 3 class labels.

Is there no way other than iterating over the elements as described in [Iterating through a scipy.sparse vector (or matrix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319014/iterating-through-a-scipy-sparse-vector-or-matrix)? I would love to have some elegant way to just somehow map(thresholdfunc()) on all elements.

Note that while it is of type csr_matrix, it isn't actually sparse as it's just the return of another function where a sparse matrix was involved.

Comment: `csc` format is much more compact when representing a column vector.

Comment: If it isn't particularly sparse, then I'd suggest working on the dense array version, `M.toarray()` (or `M.A`).

Comment: Thanks! Is it worth it to convert it to an array first if I'm only going to iterate over it once? I mean, doesn't the overhead of the conversion maybe eat the advantages of the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an array, you can discretize based on some condition with the `np.where` function. e.g.:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> np.where(x < 5, 0, 1)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

The syntax is `np.where(BOOLEAN_ARRAY, VALUE_IF_TRUE, VALUE_IF_FALSE)`.
You can chain together two `where` statements to have multiple conditions:

```
>>> np.where(x < 3, -1, np.where(x > 6, 0, 1))
array([-1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0])
```

To apply this to your data in the CSR or CSC sparse matrix, you can use the `.data` attribute, which gives you access to the internal array containing all the nonzero entries in the sparse matrix. For example:

```
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> mat = sparse.csr_matrix(x.reshape(10, 1))
>>> mat.data = np.where(mat.data < 3, -1, np.where(mat.data > 6, 0, 1))
>>> mat.toarray()
array([[ 0],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [ 1],
       [ 1],
       [ 1],
       [ 0],
       [ 0],
       [ 0]])
```

Comment: This seems nice in terms of syntactic sugar, thanks. I guess it wouldn't be much faster though, from a quick search concerning np.where() performance.

Comment: np.where is similar to other numpy vectorized functions, in which the loops are executed in compiled code. In general it will be significantly faster than iterating over elements using a Python for loop for all but the smallest arrays.