# What is the default indexing type of scipy.sparse.csr_matrix?

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` has `data`, `indices`, and `indptr` attributes.

What are the default `dtype` of `indices` and `indptr`?

For `numpy`, the default indexing type is `numpy.intp`, but that doesn't match the `dtype` of `indices` of a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`.

[Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) of scipy.sparse.csr_matrix

For my laptop:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as ss
a = ss.csr_matrix(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), dtype=float)
print(a.indices.dtype)
print(np.intp)
```

Result:

```
int32
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sparse.compressed._cs_matrix` `__init__` has

```
            idx_dtype = get_index_dtype(maxval=max(M,N))
            self.data = np.zeros(0, getdtype(dtype, default=float))
            self.indices = np.zeros(0, idx_dtype)
            self.indptr = np.zeros(self._swap((M,N))[0] + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)
```

`sparse.compressed.get_index_dtype` chooses between `np.int32` and `np.int64` depending on the shape of the matrix.  If too big to index with `32` it uses `64`.  But check that function for details.

---

```
In [789]:  np.iinfo(np.int32).max
Out[789]: 2147483647
In [790]: a=sparse.csr_matrix((1,2147483646))
In [791]: a
Out[791]: 
<1x2147483646 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [792]: a.indices.dtype
Out[792]: dtype('int32')
In [793]: a=sparse.csr_matrix((1,2147483648))
In [794]: a.indices.dtype
Out[794]: dtype('int64')
```