# How to access a function which return multiple functions in python?

Tags: python-3.x, data-mining

i come across with this function

```
def apply(graph, func, non_edges):
    # non_edges = nx.non_edges(graph)
    return ((u, v, func(u, v)) for u, v in non_edges)


def katz_dict(G, beta = 0.001, max_power=5):
    nodelist = list(G.nodes) 
    adj = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G)
    res = defaultdict(float)
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319014/
    for k in range(1, max_power + 1):
        matrix = (adj ** k).tocoo()
        for i, j, d in zip(matrix.row, matrix.col, matrix.data):
            if i == j:
                continue
            u, v = nodelist[i], nodelist[j]
            w = d * (beta ** k)
            res[(u, v)] += w
    if not G.is_directed():
            for pair in res:
                res[pair] /= 2

    return res

def list_katz_scores(G, beta=0.001, max_power=5): 
    non_edges = nx.non_edges(G)
    katz_values = katz_dict(G, beta, max_power)
    def score(u,v):
        return katz_values[(u,v)] + katz_values[(v,u)]

    return apply(G,score,non_edges)
```

To access `list_katz_scores(G, beta=0.001, max_power=5)`
i did this

```
results=list_katz_scores(G, beta=0.001, max_power=5)
print(results)
```

<generator object apply.. at 0x000002360B2F51C8>

but i want to get the values of (u,v), score. How can i do it?

Comment: Which data type do you expect to get back? `apply` does return a generator the way you defined it.

Comment: i need to get back non-edges and their scores and not generator @DavidWierichs   like edge(u,v) score

Comment: What do you get if you change the outer brackets in the `return` line of `apply` to, say, square brackets? The object you return the way you did it now *is* a generator, no?